# Installing Linux on Hardware Raid 0

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, raid

I have an msi gs70 stealth pro, with two ssd's configured in hardware raid 0 as well as a hdd. I've always installed linux (dual boot with windows) on the hdd, to avoid raid complications, but after learning more about hardware vs software raid, I'm wondering if this makes a difference? Has anyone had any experience or knowledge about installing linux on hardware raid 0? Does it change the way I need to partition the drive? In the installer, when I go to manually configure partitions, all the entries on the raid drive are doubled. Do I need to mimic what I do for each entry? Also is there any chance the the raid 0 controller might not communicate with linux correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems after messing with it for a while, that the hardware made doesn't affect things much in terms of partitioning. If you create a new partition in windows at least, unlike the default system partitions, it won't show up doubled in the linux installer. Now, depending on the distribution you use, it seems like need certain packages in order for linux to correctly use the raid partition. These are generally installed automatically and you never have to worry about them, but some distributions, KDE Neon in my case, try to automatically remove them.